# bootstrap: display modal in main while clicking in iframe

Tags: iframe, modal-dialog

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBcI6.jpg)

I'm using Bootstrap for this modal. Please view my illustration to know what I want to say.I tried this but, the result is not like in the illustration. I'm not able to display the modal.

> main.html
>
> ```
> <!-- Modal content-->
> <div class="modal-content">
>   <div class="modal-header">
>     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
>     <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
>   </div>
>   <div class="modal-body">
>     <iframe src='b.html' frameborder=0></iframe>
>   </div>
>   <div class="modal-footer">
>     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> b.html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myshow">Open Modal</button>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that because the modal does not exist in b.html.

Comment: i done that but... the modal will only appear on b. i wanted to appear in main

Comment: I think it won't appears straight forward. Unless someone else had other solutions.

Comment: https://madskristensen.net/post/iframe-cross-domain-javascript-calls this might help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, I manage to open my modal into the parent(main.html) but every time I load the b.html the modal will appear.

b.html

just added a script on b.html

```
window.parent.parent.$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

now my problem is how to display modal only when click from b.html

---

SOLUTION MY OWN PROBLEM:

added script in b.html

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     // Attach Button click event listener 
    $("#btnPopModal").click(function(){

         // show Modal
          window.parent.parent.$('#mypob').modal('show');
    });
});
```

and that's it... thanks

Comment: Using js or jquery, how can I transmit values from the inner element to the outer modal?